# Ditched me for breakfast?

Tags: prepositions

I was watching *The Santa Clarita Diet* and in one episode, a girl named Abby promises to have breakfast with a boy named Eric. However, Abby later ditches Eric to do something else. Eric finds her later and says,

> You ditched me for breakfast.

I am confused by the use of the preposition *for* in this context. To me, the sentence means the girl ditched Eric just so that she could have breakfast, as in *I exchange my life 'for' your happiness* but Abby did not have breakfast, so why would Eric use *for*? Can someone elaborate?

Comment: There is nothing in that sentence that indicates Abby *didn't* have breakfast. In fact, the grammar very strongly suggests that she *did* have breakfast. At the very least, it definitely implies that she *meant* to have breakfast. Your claim that she *didn't* have breakfast is both unsupported based on the context you've provided, but it also doesn't matter in terms of the single sentence itself.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is indeed ambiguous, but understandable. In the absence of other context, to *[ditch](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ditch_2) X for Y* would overwhelmingly mean, as you surmise, to abandon or discard X and substitute it with Y, in informal registers.

> We ditched class for opening day.
>
> She couldn't believe her own sister had ditched her for a boy.
>
> It's well past time to ditch Adobe Flash for HTMl5.

This isn't the only way to interpret *[for](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for)* with *ditch*, however—it is one of the most flexible prepositions in the language. For example, the object of *for* may represent a purpose or cause for the act of ditching—

> I watched Steve blow his brains out because you went and ditched him for your cause!  (*[The Last Hunter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087594/)*, 1980)

It's also very common for it to refer to a scope or duration for the ditching—

> She said okay, and then he ditched her for 12 years. (*[The Women of Doctor Who](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2387272/)*, 2012)
>
> Fans noticed Mel B ditched her eye patch for the concert return. ([from Noise11.com](http://www.noise11.com/news/sound-problems-wreck-spice-girls-comeback-gig-20190527), 2019)

(above film/TV references via english-corpora.org)

In your example, *for* is used roughly like *concerning* or *in respect to*, referring to the intended purpose of the original meeting. It is a compressed way of saying

> We were supposed to meet for breakfast, but you ditched me.
>
> You ditched me and our plans for breakfast.

Comment: I like to think of this as not a _ditched X for Y_, but rather just a _ditched X_ and the X, is the entire phrase _me for breakfast_. so the thing being ditched, was both the person and their breakfast plan

Comment: @MarcusGosselin Your thinking would be wrong, based on the syntax used. The sentence clearly uses *X **for** Y*, not *X **and** Y*. So, it's not clear why you'd want to interpret it in a way that the words don't indicate. (The only way your interpretation makes any sense is if the person being ditched was a cannibal and the speaker was on the menu.)

Comment: I agreed with everything you said—up until the last sentence, which doesn't mean the same thing as the original sentence at all.